# Google Drive: transfer files only over wifi keeps turning on

Tags: wi-fi, google-drive, uploads

In my android version 7.1.1 mobile, I am unable to upload files to `Google Drive` over mobile network. I am not able to disable `transfer files only over wifi` field from the `settings` of `Google Drive`. When I disable that it appears to be disabled there. However when I recheck this by clicking back button and coming to `settings` again, I can still see that `transfer files only over wifi` is enabled.

Comment: Try uninstalling Drive and again install. You won't lose data

Answer (score 0):

upgraded Google Drive and that fixed the issue.